# Merge non-merged feature branch into another feature branch with Git

Tags: git, github, merge

My company has a Git workflow that looks something like this:

- Create feature branch from pristine branch (we use a base branch called "develop", but you can think of this as "master")
- Do the work you need to do in this feature branch, and commit your changes
- Occasionally, rebase your feature branch with the develop branch
- When the work in your feature branch is complete, commit and push to the remote feature branch on GitHub
- Create a pull request to merge your feature branch into the develop branch, which gets code reviewed by another developer
- Once the code review is completed, the feature branch is merged into the develop branch, and the feature branch is deleted

This works when you're dealing with a serial workflow, but when you've pushed your changes from your feature branch and are waiting on the other developer to review and merge your changes, you probably want to take on another piece of work, which means repeating the above process.

In our case, we're currently creating our feature branches from the develop branch, so the work I just completed isn't yet available (it's still in limbo, waiting to be merged into the develop branch by another developer). The question I have is, what if the work I'm doing in my *new* feature branch depends on the work I just completed in my previous feature branch? Should I be initially branching my new feature branch from my as-of-yet unmerged feature branch instead of the develop branch? If I've already created my new feature branch from the develop branch, is getting the changes I'm missing from the unmerged branch as simple as doing a `git merge [unmerged-branch]` within my new branch?

Hopefully this explanation -- as well as the workflow itself! -- makes sense. I've gotten myself into some weird situations where I'm unclear the state of my code, so I'm trying to figure out a workflow that gives me the flexibility to merge in changes from other feature branches while still getting upstream changes at any time.

Comment: Branching from develop and merging your unapproved feature branch is effectively the same as just branching from the feature branch.

Comment: You have explained it perfectly. I don't want to wait on code review to get started on the next feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The question I have is, what if the work I'm doing in my new feature
>   branch depends on the work I just completed in my previous feature
>   branch? Should I be initially branching my new feature branch from my
>   as-of-yet unmerged feature branch instead of the develop branch?

The way you're describing it, yes, you would.  However, I'd be concerned about potentially going down the path of working off of "unapproved / unreviewed" work, as if your code review results in significant changes, you may find yourself redoing a lot of work.

> If I've already created my new feature branch from the develop branch,
>   is getting the changes I'm missing from the unmerged branch as simple
>   as doing a git merge [unmerged-branch] within my new branch?

Yep.  Should be. :)

Comment: Your first comment is one of the main concerns I have: relying on unapproved work. If there's a change I need to make to the branch that's being reviewed, then I also need to merge the changes I've made in that branch into my new feature branch, and it starts to get hairy. Fortunately, I can't really foresee a situation where there would be more than one feature branch under review, for any given developer, at the same time, so maybe it's not altogether _too_ painful.

Comment: I have the same flow with squash commits on merge, does it make some difference? I merge 5 commits of feature1 branch info feature2 branch and then make a rebase on develop branch (where it has 1 merge commit) will the rebase create conflicts? thank you