# Branching off a non-merged feature branch?

Tags: git

I currently need to complete some work that depends on another feature branch which hasn't merged into develop yet, I know I can branch off this feature branch and do my work.

The main question I have is, won't this result in duplicate commits appearing when it's time to merge my work into develop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge non-merged feature branch into another feature branch with Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111851/merge-non-merged-feature-branch-into-another-feature-branch-with-git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a technical point of view: No, there will be no duplicates if you simply merge the branches back. It doesn't even matter in what order you merge the feature branches.

However, from a project management perspective this could be a bit weird. Say your second feature (F2) is merged before the first (F1). This could introduce potentially untested changes from F1 because with the merge you get all commits from the F1 branch up to the branch point of the second branch. It's just something to be aware of. If you don't intend to merge the F2 before F1, there should be no worries. Likewise, if F2 is just a sub-feature of F1, you could merge it back into F1 and then F1 into develop.

Answer (score 2):

> won't this result in duplicate commits appearing when it's time to merge my work into `develop`?

No, but you won't be able to merge your work into `develop` without merging also the commits from the `feature` branch.

If feature branch is merged when you finally merge your own work to `develop`, all the common commits won't be merged twice.

The best practice is, before merging your work to `develop`:

- check that the `feature` branch has been merged to `develop`
- fetch from `origin`
- rebase your work on top of `origin/develop` (any common commits from `feature` won't be part of the rebase)