# Conflicts while merging feature branch into the master branch in GitHub

Tags: github, merge

While merging a feature branch with the master of GitHub, I have the same scenario and workflow as mentioned in the below question :

[Merge non-merged feature branch into another feature branch with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111851/merge-non-merged-feature-branch-into-another-feature-branch-with-git)

I have the master branch. Feature branch1 and the development for feature branch1 is already completed, the code needs to be reviewed and branch should be merged.

Meanwhile, a feature branch branch2 gets created and a piece of work for branch2 depends on code developed in branch1. Since the same code needed in branch2, I have merged and committed the changes in the master branch from branch1 once code review is completed.

Now, I am supposed to get the latest code of master branch in branch2 to start my work in branch2. So, I have merged my feature branch2 again from the master branch.
Is this the correct way to do it, or do I need to delete my feature branch2 and create a new branch again?
Also, since my branch2 was merged from master branch after it was created, when I pushed my changes, that merge was maintained as a history of that branch that will ultimately go to the history of my master branch(as a comment if I do Squash and merge), which is fine.
Now, feature branch2 shows conflicts instead of saying automatically merge. Was this due to the branch1 merge done previously? If so, is there any way to get an automatic merge option into the master branch without any need to resolve conflicts. As I am sure I have already merged the changes from my master branch into feature branch2.