# How to rebase on branch that is not merged yet

Tags: git, merge, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

I worked on `feature1` branch - 5 commits, then create a merge request (with **commits squash**) into `story` branch and hand it over to code review.

The review and merge is not done immediately, so I create `feature2` branch from the `story` branch and continue to work on it. The `story` branch does not have the `feature1` yet, neither has the `feature2` branch.

In the meantime the `feature1` is merged. I'm used to do rebase of my `feature2` branch to be up-to-date with the updated `story` branch, and eventually resolve conflicts with my new code done in `feature2`.

Is there a way to avoid conflicts? Can I bring the changes in `feature1` into my `feature2` branch before the merge request is finished, so I could prevent the conflicts on rebase?

I tried to rebase `feature2` on `feature1` before the merge, and then after some work rebase it on `story` branch when the `feature1` is merged, but it failed because `story` has only one squashed commit, while my `feature2` branch has 5 commits from `feature1`

I saw this [Merge non-merged feature branch into another feature branch with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111851/merge-non-merged-feature-branch-into-another-feature-branch-with-git) question, but the `--squash` option is not used there.

Comment: I think this is a great argument for avoiding --squash.   A squash merge is all pain, no gain.

Comment: It seems like you want to rebase `feature2` onto `feature1` rather than the other way around, but maybe you're using the phrase differently than I.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thank you, my fault, I used that as you suggest, I just did not wrote it correctly. I like the `--squash` because of the clean history on the story (develop, main) branch from witch we generate the changelog